# ObservableCollection and DisplayMemberBinding

Tags: wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm trying to fill `ListBox` by `ObservableCollection`. But when I add new item nothing displayed, only empty item adding.

There are fragments of my code:
`XAML`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" SelectedItem="{Binding Point}">
<ListView.View>
<GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
 <GridViewColumn Header ="X" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding = "{Binding Path=ValueX, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<GridViewColumn Header ="Y" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding = "{Binding Path=ValueY, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Window class

```
var value = new Value();
var viewModel = new ViewModel(value);
DataContext = viewModel;
InitializeComponent();
```

Value class

```
private const Point POINT = null;
private readonly ObservableCollection<Point> _points = new ObservableCollection<Point>();
public Value() {
Point = POINT;
Points = _points;
}

public Point Point { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Point> Points { get; private set; }
public double ValueX { get; set; }
public int ValueY { get; set; }
```

ViewModel class

```
private readonly Value _value;
public ViewModel(Value value) {
_value = value;
}
public Point Point {
get { return _value.Point; }
set {
_value.Point = value;
OnPropertyChanged("Point");
}
}

public ObservableCollection<Point> Points {
get { return _value.Points; }
}

private RelayCommand _addCommand;

        public ICommand AddCommand {
            get {
                if (_addCommand == null) {
                    _addCommand = new RelayCommand(Add);
                }
                return _addCommand;
            }
        }

        private void Add(object obj) {
            Points.Add(new Point(ValueX, ValueY));
            ValueX = 0;
            ValueY = 0;
        }
public double ValueX {
        get {
            return _value.ValueX;
        }
        set {
            if(Math.Abs(_value.ValueX - value) < Mathematics.EPSILON) return;
            _value.ValueX = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ValueX");
        }
    }

    public int ValueY {
        get { return _value.ValueY; }
        set {
            if(_value.ValueX == value) return;
            _value.ValueY = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ValueY");
        }
    }
```

and Point class

```
public class Point {
    public readonly double ValueX;
    public readonly double ValueY;

    public Point(double valueX, double valueY) {
        ValueX = valueX;
        ValueY = valueY;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return (ValueX + "   " + ValueY);
    }
}
```

When i try to add new item, new item is added but nothing is displayed. What reason can be here?

Comment: You seem to be confused... why have you implemented your data type properties in your view model? You shouldn't have `ValueX` and `ValueY` there with `OnPropertyChanged`... you should have *that* code in your `Point` data type. You should see a binding error in the Output window in Visual Studio... what does it say?

Comment: No, there is no any exeptions

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > WPF Trace Settings and set the 'Data Binding' option to 'Warning' or 'Error'. You can find out more from the [How to: Display WPF Trace Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx) page at MSDN.

Comment: @Sheridan these comments should be answers.  They fix the op's problem

Comment: @GarryVass, the question author has not said that his problem is fixed yet, but I will copy my comments to an answer if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you bind `ItemsSource` to `ObservableCollection<Point>` it means that each item is of a `Point` type which has `ValueX` and `ValueY` declared as fields which are not valid binding source. Change them to properties:

```
public double ValueX { get; private set; }
public double ValueY { get; private set; }
```

Besides you use `Mode=TwoWay` for something that is read only. This should be changed to `OneWay`. If you want to leave `TwoWay` binding then remove `private` from the setter but then also you'll need to change `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` to be some `TextBox` instead of using `DisplayMemberBinding` which is for display only.

Comment: It's impossible because i should have ability change them during executing. User should change them. I edited ViewModel

Comment: But then why you marked them as [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx)?